# Concatenating strings in the return set of a GROUP BY clause in CockroachDB

Tags: mysql, sql, cockroachdb

Does CockroachDB support something like MySQL’s `group_concat()` function that lets me concatenate a column’s values in a GROUP BY group?

For instance, if I wanted to concatenate all of the item descriptions in an order into a single string. Given the following sample data:

```
Order_ID | Item_ID | Description
---------|---------|------------
1        | 1001    | Apple
1        | 1002    | Banana
2        | 1001    | Apple
2        | 1003    | Orange
```

I'd like to then return:

```
Order_ID | Items
---------|--------------
1        | AppleBanana
2        | AppleOrange
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `concat_agg` function on the column you want to concatenate together.

Using your example above, you’d run:

```
SELECT concat_agg(Description)
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Order_ID
ORDER BY Order_ID;
```

This will produce an output with all of the descriptions concatenated, grouped by order id.